# List Adapter duplicando posições no ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Tenho uma classe chamada "AdapterListJogadores" que estende a classe BaseAdapter e nele eu inflo um layout que contem um CheckBox e um ImageView.

**Classe AdapterListJogadores**

```
public class AdapterListJogadores extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Jogador> jogador;

    public AdapterListJogadores(Context context, List<Jogador> jogador){
        this.jogador = jogador;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public List<Jogador> getJogador(){
        return jogador;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return jogador.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Jogador getItem(int position) {
        return jogador.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ItemSuporte{
        CheckBox txtNomeJogador;
        ImageView imgPosicao;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("Position: ", String.valueOf(position)); //Mostra a posição recebida como parametro do getView no log 
        // Resultado do log, logo abaixo

        ItemSuporte item;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_jogador, null);

            item = new ItemSuporte();

            item.txtNomeJogador = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtNomeJogador);
            item.imgPosicao = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPosicao);

            convertView.setTag(item);

            item.txtNomeJogador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    Jogador jogador = getItem(position);
                    jogador.setMarcado(cb.isChecked());
                }
            });

        } else {
            item = (ItemSuporte) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Jogador jogador = getItem(position);

        item.txtNomeJogador.setText(jogador.getNomeJogador());
        item.txtNomeJogador.setChecked(jogador.isMarcado());

        int posicao = jogador.getPosicao();
        switch (posicao){
            case 0:
                item.imgPosicao.setImageResource(R.mipmap.jogador);
                break;
            case 1:
                item.imgPosicao.setImageResource(R.mipmap.goleiro);
                break;
            default:
                item.imgPosicao.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bola);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**Classe Jogador**

```
public class Jogador {
    int _idJogador;
    String _nomeJogador;
    int _posicao;
    private boolean marcado;

    public Jogador(int idJogador, String nomeJogador, int posicao) {
        this._idJogador = idJogador;
        this._nomeJogador = nomeJogador;
        this._posicao = posicao;
    }

    // getting Id
    public int getIdJogador() {
        return this._idJogador;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setIdJogador(int idJogador) {
        this._idJogador = idJogador;
    }

    // getting nome
    public String getNomeJogador() {
        return this._nomeJogador;
    }

    // setting nome
    public void setNomeJogador(String nomeJogador) {
        this._nomeJogador = nomeJogador;
    }

    // getting posicao
    public int getPosicao() {
        return this._posicao;
    }

    // setting posicao
    public void setPosicao(int posicao) {
        this._posicao = posicao;
    }

    public boolean isMarcado() {
        return marcado;
    }

    public void setMarcado(boolean marcado) {
        this.marcado = marcado;
    }
}
```

Ja na minha activity eu tenho um ListView que recebe os valores desse adapter e coloca na tela pro usuário.

```
 public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        final DBAdapterJogador dbJogador = new DBAdapterJogador(this);
        dbJogador.open();

        final List<Jogador> jogador = dbJogador.listar();
        final AdapterListJogadores adapter = new AdapterListJogadores(this, jogador);
        lstJogadores.setAdapter(adapter);
        dbJogador.close();
}
```

Esse é o resultado que tenho no log quando executo o projeto com 15 itens no meu banco.

```
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 0
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 1
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 2
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 3
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 4
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 5
02-11 16:20:11.386    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 6
02-11 16:20:11.387    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 7
02-11 16:20:11.387    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 8
02-11 16:20:11.387    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 9
02-11 16:20:11.387    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 10
02-11 16:20:11.388    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 11
02-11 16:20:11.388    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 12
02-11 16:20:11.388    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 0
02-11 16:20:11.389    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 1
02-11 16:20:11.390    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 2
02-11 16:20:11.394    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 3
02-11 16:20:11.398    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 4
02-11 16:20:11.400    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 5
02-11 16:20:11.402    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 6
02-11 16:20:11.403    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 7
02-11 16:20:11.406    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 8
02-11 16:20:11.408    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 9
02-11 16:20:11.411    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 10
02-11 16:20:11.414    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 11
02-11 16:20:11.423    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 12
02-11 16:20:11.451    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 0
02-11 16:20:11.452    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 1
02-11 16:20:11.453    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 2
02-11 16:20:11.454    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 3
02-11 16:20:11.454    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 4
02-11 16:20:11.454    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 5
02-11 16:20:11.455    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 6
02-11 16:20:11.455    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 7
02-11 16:20:11.455    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 8
02-11 16:20:11.456    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 9
02-11 16:20:11.456    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 10
02-11 16:20:11.456    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 11
02-11 16:20:11.456    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 12
02-11 16:20:11.696    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 0
02-11 16:20:11.696    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 1
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 2
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 3
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 4
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 5
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 6
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 7
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 8
02-11 16:20:11.697    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 9
02-11 16:20:11.698    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 10
02-11 16:20:11.698    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 11
02-11 16:20:11.698    3677-3677/favarin.com.br.pernetas E/Position:﹕ 12
```

Com isso estou tendo um problema que quando seleciono um CheckBox com posicao 15 (por exemplo) ele seleciona automaticamente o item da posição 3 e pega todos os valores dessa posição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está a atribuir o `OnClickListener()` apenas quando a `convertView` é nula.
Quando a view é reaproveitada para outro item a `position`, que foi passada ao listener, mantém o seu valor inicial, aquele que tinha quando o listener foi criado(note que ela é declarada `final int position`).

Passe a atribuição do `OnClickListener()` para fora do bloco `if(convertView == null)`

```
if(convertView == null){
    ....
    ....
} else {
    item = (ItemSuporte) convertView.getTag();
}

item.txtNomeJogador.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
        Jogador jogador = getItem(position);
        jogador.setMarcado(cb.isChecked());
    }
});
```

Assim, quando a execução passa pelo `else`, o *listener* anteriormente aplicado é substituído por um novo com o valor correcto de `position`.